# Mediawiki to display different links to different geographic locations

Tags: mediawiki

**Scenario**: An intranet site is accessed from two different countries through different site names. We use mediawiki as knowledge base and wish to reference this intranet site. mediawiki is used by teams in both countries.

Currently we are providing two different URLs in the wiki. example:

> *Country one:* ur1.**in**.intranet\hello\world
>   *Country two:* ur1.**en**.intranet\hello\world

**Problem:** *How do we ensure that the correct (accessible) intranet site address is presented to the person accessing from each country?*

I have tried to find information using wiki templates. Say, while authoring, all users must use a specific template {{Intranet_Page | < URL >}}

In the template, a code could check the IP of the accessing user and determine which site name has to be used. I was unable to find the right special word for finding the IP. :(

*Is there any way... PHP modifications / Templates / others?*

Comment: I would like to help but I am not sure I understand your issue. 
You would like to have links that would adapt, depending of the country of the IP who access the page, is that it ?

Comment: Thanks @Euloiix. Yes. In this case, it is the domain names instead of IP.

Comment: Did you look into parser functions? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want. If I understand correctly you want a wiki page to contain a link to an external website, which exists in multiple variants depending on country. The page should be served to the visiting user with the link rendered in the correct country variant.

This is similar to the issue of linking a translatable page but redirecting the user to the user's (interface) language's subpage thereof. To do so, MediaWiki core provides [Special:MyLanguage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Extension:Translate/Page_translation_administration#markup), a redirect special page.

A redirecting special page is the easiest solution for such issues because:

- the page HTML doesn't need to vary based on each parameter (in your case country) but can be cached identical;
- you gain a canonical URL for the resource, which is the same for everyone to link and yet brings everyone to the correct variant.

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Special_pages on how to make a special page and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoIP or similar to extract country from IP.